# How i can find why my same latex code produces different results?

Tags: latex, tex

I have two a pc and a laptop with Linux Mint same version.
Exactly same tex code but at laptop pdf product is ok, but on pc pdf not shows up.
How i can check the difference of texlive? Are at newest version.

```
\includepdf[pages=24-26]{boulemata}
```

Comment: Can you make a diff from both .log files?

Comment: Please also elaborate what you mean with "pdf not shows up"? Is the pdf not created? Does it not open in your pdf viewer?